# What is the phone storage in Android devices?

Tags: android, android-intent

I can pass sdcard location to my adb command using

```
file:///sdcard/Android/screen.bmp
```

What is the equivalent string, if my file is saved in phone memory instead of sdcard, will it be

```
file:///phone/Android/screen.bmp
```

Comment: phone memory? you mean system?

Comment: I mean, default memory when SD card is not inserted. I think, in this case camera images etc are saved to phone memory.

Comment: try it with its something like `/mnt/sdcard0/ /mnt/sdcard/ /storage/sdcard0/ /storage/sdcard/` . My phone didnt use sdcard and my path to internal storage is `/mnt/sdcard0/`

Answer (score 0):

That isn't necessarily how you access things saved internally on your phone.

Keep in mind how you save an image to internal storage:

```
Bitmap bitmap = ______; //get your bitmap however
try {
    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput("desiredFilename.png", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fos);
    fos.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("saveToInternalStorage()", e.getMessage());
    Log.e("Saving the bitmap",e.getMessage());
}
```

---

Now, to go read it, we just get the context, and call `getFileStreamPath(filename)` on it.

```
Bitmap retrievedImage;
String filename = "desiredFilename.png";
try {
    File filePath = context.getFileStreamPath(filename);
    FileInputStream fi = new FileInputStream(filePath);
    retrievedImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fi);
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e("Retrieving the image", e.getMessage());
}
```

You can read more about this [here](http://www.e-nature.ch/tech/saving-loading-bitmaps-to-the-android-device-storage-internal-external/).